# Unable to run npm command in ansible awx_task container

Tags: docker, path, ansible, ansible-awx

I have been using ansible core for some time now and expanding my team so the need for ansible awx has become a little more pressing. I have been working at it for a week now and I think it's time to shout for help.

We had a process of replacing the baseurl of angularjs apps with some variable using ansible and set some settings before we compile it (currently thinking of a different way of doing this using build server like TeamCity but not right now we we are trying to be up with ansible awx).

ansible core checks out the code from the git branch version , replaces the variables and zip it to s3 etc.

Knowing that, the ansible awx host was configured with the nvm then node was installed and the `.nvm` mapped to `/home/awx/.nvm`
I have also mapped a bashrc to `/home/awx/.bashrc`. When I log into the awx_task container `docker exec -it awx_task /bin/bash` I see the below:

```
[root@awx ~]# npm --version
 5.5.1
[root@awx ~]# echo $PATH /home/awx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
[root@awx ~]# env
NVM_DIR=/home/awx/.nvm
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
HOSTNAME=awx
NVM_CD_FLAGS=
DO_ANSIBLE_HOME=/opt/do_ansible_awx_home
PWD=/home/awx
HOME=/home/awx
affinity:container==eb57afe832eaa32472812d0cd8b614be6df213d8e866f1d7b04dfe109a887e44
TERM=xterm
NVM_BIN=/home/awx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/bin
SHLVL=1
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
PATH=/home/awx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin                                                                                                                                      

LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
_=/usr/bin/env

[root@awx ~]# cat /home/awx/.bashrc
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

All the volume mappings, etc were done with the installer role templates and tasks so the output above is the same after multiple docker restart and reinstall running the ansible awx installer playbook. But during the execution of the playbook that makes use of the npm, it seems it has a different env `PATH:  /var/lib/awx/venv/ansible/bin:/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

[image: AWX job execution screenshot]

At this point, I am not sure whether I failed to configure the path properly or other containers like awx_web should also be configured etc.

I have also noticed the env `NVM_BIN` and modified the npm playbook to include the path to the npm executable:

```
  - name: Running install to build npm modules
    npm:
      path: "{{ bps_git_checkout_folder }}"
      executable: "{{ lookup('env','NVM_BIN') }}/npm"
```

and it doens't even show during execution thus pointing at different path and env variables being loaded.

[image]

I will be grateful if you could shed some lights on whatever I am doing wrongly.

Thanks in advance

**EDITS** : After implementing @sergei suggestion I have used the extra vars `npm_bin: /home/awx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/bin`

I have changed the task to look like:

```
   - name: Running install to build npm modules
     npm:
       path: "{{ bps_git_checkout_folder }}"
       executable: "{{ npm_bin }}/npm"
```

But it produced this result:

```
 <127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
 <127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~root && sleep 0'
 <127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1579790680.4419668-165048670233209 `" && echo 
 ansible-tmp-1579790680.4419668-165048670233209="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1579790680.4419668-165048670233209 `" ) && 
 sleep 0'
 Using module file /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/modules/packaging/language/npm.py
 <127.0.0.1> PUT /var/lib/awx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-10173xtu81x_o/tmpd40htayd TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1579790680.4419668-165048670233209/AnsiballZ_npm.py
 <127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1579790680.4419668-165048670233209/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1579790680.4419668-165048670233209/AnsiballZ_npm.py && sleep 0'
 <127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/libexec/platform-python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1579790680.4419668-165048670233209/AnsiballZ_npm.py && sleep 0'
 <127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1579790680.4419668-165048670233209/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
 The full traceback is:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1579790680.4419668-165048670233209/AnsiballZ_npm.py", line 114, in <module>
 _ansiballz_main()
 File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1579790680.4419668-165048670233209/AnsiballZ_npm.py", line 106, in _ansiballz_main
 invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
 File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1579790680.4419668-165048670233209/AnsiballZ_npm.py", line 49, in invoke_module
imp.load_module('__main__', mod, module, MOD_DESC)
 File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/imp.py", line 235, in load_module
 return load_source(name, filename, file)
 File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/imp.py", line 170, in load_source
 module = _exec(spec, sys.modules[name])
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _exec
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap…
 PLAY RECAP 
 *********************************************************************
 localhost                  : ok=5    changed=4    unreachable=0 failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I have also tried to use shell module directly with the following:

```
  - name: Running npm install 
    shell: "{{ npm_bin }}/npm install"
    args:
    chdir: "{{ bps_git_checkout_folder }}"
```

That has produced this instead:

```
 <127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
 <127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~root && sleep 0'
 <127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1579791187.453365-253173616238218 `" && echo 
 ansible-tmp-1579791187.453365-253173616238218="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1579791187.453365-253173616238218 `" ) && 
 sleep 0'
 Using module file /usr/lib/python3.6/site- packages/ansible/modules/commands/command.py
 <127.0.0.1> PUT /var/lib/awx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-10395h1ga8fw3/tmpepeig729 TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1579791187.453365-253173616238218/AnsiballZ_command.py
 <127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1579791187.453365-253173616238218/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1579791187.453365-253173616238218/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'
 <127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/libexec/platform-python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1579791187.453365-253173616238218/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'
 <127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1579791187.453365-253173616238218/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "/home/awx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/bin/npm install",
    "delta": "0:00:00.005528",
    "end": "2020-01-23 14:53:07.928843",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "/home/awx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/bin/npm install",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": "/opt/do_ansible_awx_home/gh/deployments/sandbox/bps",
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "stdin_add_newline": true,
            "strip_empty_ends": true,
            "warn": true
        }
     },
     "msg": "non-zero return code",
     "rc": 127,
     …
     PLAY RECAP 
   *********************************************************************
   localhost                  : ok=5    changed=4    unreachable=0 failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Not really seeing what's wrong here . Grateful if anybody can share some lights on this.

Comment: Can you try passing the needed ENV vars as `environment:` at the task level?

Comment: trying that. Thanks for this idea

Comment: @sergei I tried the suggestion but it didn't get anywhere. I don't really see what is wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Where is your packages sitting? In the host or inside the container? All execution is in the task container.

If you're npm files are sitting on the 'host' and not in the container then you have to refer to the host that the containers are sitting on to to refer to the path.

Comment: Best would be to ask questions as a comment and then edit your answer afterwards. That way answer stay clear :) PS: Welcome!